# Why linear forces can be added whereas torque cannot (example: internal combustion engines)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

In a internal combustion engine, for example, we know only one piston is fired at one time, no matter on the number of cylinders in the engine: 4, 6, 8, 12, etc.
Why cannot two pistons be fired at the same time?

In fact, linear forces can be added: for example, when two or more people push a stuck car, by adding engines to an airplane.

In a conveyor belt there cannot be 2 electric motors.

Why torque cannot be added whereas linear forces do?

Comment: Sorry but this seems *non sequitur*: how is " Why can't pistons be fired at the same time" related to adding torque?

Comment: According to common sense (engineers who are not engine designers are included), 2 pistons fired at the same time would increase torque, and this never happens. There is not an invalid argument.

Comment: wow... I have really misunderstood what you meant by that.  Thanks for clarifying

Comment: -1. Please can you provide a reference for the claim that 2 pistons fired at the same time does not increase torque? And also for why there cannot be two electric motors for a conveyor belt? For those of us who are not automotive/conveyor belt engineers and do not find it obvious.

Comment: -1 No research effort

Comment: +sofky How do you know I haven't searched this question in another forums? Please reconsider yourself. +sammy gerbil. If you're asking me to provide references, why do you dislike this question a priori?

Comment: It is pointless looking for an explanation of something which is not true. If you think what you are asking is true, provide some evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torques can be added.

Imagine a large horizontal wheel that turns a shaft. Now if one man applies a force to turn the wheel, the net torque will be some value. If two or three men join in and apply forces in the same direction (clockwise/anti-clockwise) then the net torque will increase.

This is commonly applied in machines such as human powered capstans...

[image]

This is fine if the machines have a low RPM such as merry-go-rounds and capstan shafts. But in high RPM machines, the complication to having multiple torques acting at the same time is that they need to be synced perfectly and they need to act at the exact same instant in time. Small variations in timing could result in large vibrations on the shaft.

In high RPM machine aircraft turbines, the torque added by each blade is not "timed", instead, the torque acts continuously as the blade revolves around the shaft. So multiple blades around the periphery of a shaft act in perfect unison to generate a large combined torque.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of "can" it's a matter of "should."  If every cylinder fires at a different time, the torque is smoother because it is evenly distributed.  If you had multiple cylinders firing at the same time, you'd have a period of time with much more torque, and then a longer region with no torque.

Comment: I consider you're right, and also, two pistons, two motors, etc. must be synchronized with the same speed (or velocity) in order to add force or torque.